# Can I use C++ as a full-featured development language for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

I'm a C++ developer with an experience and now I want to get some experience in Windows Phone 8 development. I'm interested will I be able to use C++ for any kind of WinPhone 8 application development? Or C++ has only limited support in this environment and I have to learn C#?

Comment: as a side comment, i never understood not liking something you dont know

Comment: Yes, C++11 is a first class citizen on Phone8.  There's a learning curve, you'll need to use the WinRT api to make OS calls.  That's only not painful if you use the C++/CX language extension.  Just try it with VS2012 and a handful of samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use it as a primary development language. That being said your experience is going to be much better if you use C# because it is what the development tools (WPF designer) intend you to use.  Additionally in industry I think you will be hard pressed to find people who want general purpose apps written in C++ simply because you don't like C#.